# Adding Multiple Datasets and total

Tags: reporting-services

[Phased Budget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woUDu.png)

Pretty new to all this.

I'm building a report in SSRS with multiple datasets.

The report has 12 trading periods and an Annual Total.

I've added a total line which sums the budget for 2 datasets using an expression.

The total works fine for the Annual Total but not for any of the periods. It just shows the annual total in each month.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the code of what you have done so far.

Comment: or an image of what your data looks like or what you are trying to achieve (even an Excel mockup). It is hard to guess from the information given - are the trading periods in rows or columns? What are the fields in the two datasets?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve (image in original message). I have a Net Margin Total which is adding the budget from Dataset 1 and Dataset 2. It works for the FY19 Total but not for the periods. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use a formula similar to the GROSS MARGIN.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I need to add 2 datasets together. It worked for the total column but not for any of the months. (See image in original post) Could you post the formula you are suggesting please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom code to store DataSet1 values to an array and then use the stored values to calculate net margin.

Add the following custom code to your report

```
Dim i1 As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer

Dim sumarray(12) As Decimal 

Public Function setSum(ByVal v As Decimal) As Decimal

sumarray(i1) = v

i1 = i1 + 1
Return v

End Function

Public Function getSum() As Decimal

i2 = i2 + 1
Return sumarray(i2-1)

End Function
```

For your gross margin monthly(dataset1) total use the expression:

```
 = Code.setSum( SUM(Fields!Bud.Value) )
```

For your net margin monthly total (dataset2) use the expression:

```
 = SUM(Fields!Bud.Value)  + Code.getSum()
```